# TF-IDF extracting keywords

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

Working on function somewhat like this:

```python
def get_feature_name_by_tfidf(text_to_process):
    with open(master_path + '\\additional_stopwords.txt', 'r') as f:
        additional_stop_words = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
    stop_words = text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS.union(set(additional_stop_words))
    tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 4), min_df=0, stop_words=stop_words)
    tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(text_to_process.split(','))
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tf.get_feature_names())
    feature_names_with_tags = {k: v for k, v in dict(tagged).items() if v != 'VBP'}
    return list(feature_names_with_tags.keys())
```

Which return the list of keywords in the passed text.
Is there any way to get the keywords in the same case as it is provided?
Like passed string

Input:

```python
a = "TIME is the company where I work"
```

Instead of getting keyword list as:

```python
['time', 'company']
```

I like to get:

```python
['TIME', 'company']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, TfidfVectorizer converts words to lowercase.Use this line:

```
  tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word',lowercase=False, ngram_range=(1, 4), min_df=0, stop_words=stop_words)
```

and it should work.  Use this link for ref. [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

Comment: In that case, of course, `Time`, `TIME`, and `time` would be 3 different terms (there is a reason for converting everything to lowercase first)

Comment: That's true. But, the use case requires it in that way.